# Finding out actual dip and dip direction of refractor

Tags: geophysics, seismic, homework

We have two traveltive curves for first arrivals (direct and refracted) from a dipping refractor in the forward and reverse directions along a profile line.
my question is:
Is there a logical way (non-descriptive) to determine the actual dip and the dip direction of the refractor?
I have already done the computations for velocity V1=2000 m/s, apparent velocities V2=2820 m/s, V2'=7690 m/s, dip φ=-15 degrees and critical angle ic=37,6 degrees.[image]